# Select rows from one table based on values in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these 3 tables, `tblUsers` `tblFriends` and `tblOnline`with the following data:

```
tblUsers

id username
1  john
2  jack
3  mike
4  paul

tblFriends

id User1 User2 Active
1  2     1     True  



tblOnline

id ConnId UserId
3  aaaa22 2
4  bbbb33 3
```

I want to retreive all the rows from `tblOnline` for user `john` who has the id of `1`, based on `UserId` column in `tblOnline`, whether or not `john` and that `UserId` are friends (based on the `tblFriends` table).

In this particular instance I expect to get the id 3 row from `tblOnline` since john and jack are friends and jack is in the `tblOnline`  table (they are friends since there is a match for their ids in `tblFriends` `user1` and `user2` columnns).

```
tblOnlineDTO

[Table("tblOnline")]
    public class OnlineDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ConnId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserDTO Users { get; set; }

    }
```

FriendDTO

```
[Table("tblFriends")]
    public class FriendDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int User1 { get; set; }
        public int User2 { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("User1")]
        public virtual UserDTO Users1 { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User2")]
        public virtual UserDTO Users2 { get; set; }
    }
```

UserDTO

```
[Table("tblUsers")]
    public class UserDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

So to just get all the rows from `tblOnline` I would do the following:

```
db.Online.ToArray().Select(x => new OnlineVM(x)).ToList();
```

But how do I modify that based on other conditions I mentioned, if at all possible?

Comment: You ask "But how do I modify that based on other conditions I mentioned, if at all possible?", but I don't see where you mentioned that.  Please clarify.

Comment: Basically the first paragraph, I want to retreive all the rows from tblOnline for user john who has the id of 1, based on UserId column in tblOnline, whether or not john and that UserId are friends (based on the tblFriends table).

Comment: There are 3 tables involved but you showed the code for only one. Please post the other two. In EF related questions entity models are much more important than tables. You don't expect us to write joins when we have nice navigation properties, right :)

Comment: @IvanStoev just did

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately you have no inverse navigation properties, so we are back to join case.

Comment: I am open to modifying the DTOs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
var userName = "john";
var online = db.Online
    .Where(o => db.Friend.Any(f => 
        (f.User1 == o.UserId && f.Users2.Username == userName) ||
        (f.User2 == o.UserId && f.Users1.Username == userName)))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(o => new OnlineVM(o))
    .ToList();
```

The main difficulty of the filter criteria comes from the `tblFriends` link table structure, which requires us to check both pairs if one is online and other is the user in question, and vise versa.